# How can I tell if a JS function is being called somewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, developer-tools

I've adopted a Drupal site that has a lot going on as far as Javascript is concerned. There are many separate files, both libraries and custom code.

I'm trying to get the ScrollDepth analytics plugin working and I see that the `jquery.scrolldepth.min.js` file is being loaded but I can't actually tell if the function is being called somewhere. This is making it difficult to diagnose why it isn't working.

Is there a way, using developer tools or otherwise, to tell if `jQuery.scrollDepth()` is actually being called?

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in it? Or modify the file and put a logging statement in it?

Comment: as @Bergi suggested you can put a break point in your js function and in the developer tools you can look at the `call stack` to see where it is being called from.

Comment: grep for `.scrollDepth` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the editor you're using, you can do a global search for a line in the files in whatever directory. For example, in Sublime Text, you can do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and enter your search query for `jQuery.scrollDepth()`.

In Chrome, you can set breakpoints to step through your scripts, but if you're not getting errors, you'll be stumbling through the source blind until you find something. Compared to that, I think the global search approach may be more efficient in your case.

You can also combine the two approaches... Look for where it's being called in the source, and then find that relevant line in Chrome sources and set a breakpoint. Or, better yet, **if your scripts are all concatenated, just open the `Sources` tab in developer tools and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for that line**.

Comment: Also look for `$.scrollDepth`. And hope that the "jQuery" identifier was minimised nowhere. Better search for `.scrollDepth` alone, it'll still find everything

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of global search in Sublime Text. That worked well.

Comment: @Vecta, cool glad it worked for you. Yeah it's not an obvious feature, but it's very useful!

Comment: dbl-click each file in the source's left pane to "open" it, then [ctrl]+[f] to search all of them at once.